# "[shuttle]" tag appeared, seems redundant to "[space-shuttle]"

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This month a couple of questions have used the [shuttle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shuttle) tag. Both were clearly asking about STS which is covered by [space-shuttle].  I've edited both questions and replaced the tag; can [shuttle] be deleted or merged or something?

Comment: I think if the tag remains completely unused for 24 hours, it just self-deletes. Consider this the definitive experiment ;-)

Comment: uhoh is right. You did excellent community moderation here. The shuttle tag should self-delete soon.

Comment: We could make shuttle a synonym to prevent it from popping up again. I do think we're fairly confident it is only used in reference to the STS, right? I know the generic descriptor can apply to other things, but the odds of it needing to be a separate tag are low I think, and we could always remove the synonym in that eventuality. Reply if you agree with my assessment and I'll make the synonym.

Comment: Thanks, I've only seen it these two times. The questions were https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39502/did-the-shuttle-srbs-have-separation-motors and  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39315/stars-visible-during-ascent Both appeared to be clearly STS related to me.  Whatever makes less work and most sense is OK with me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and made [shuttle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shuttle) a synonym of [space-shuttle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-shuttle) to prevent this from popping up again.